# Git download branch to local machine

Tags: git, github

I create push origin 'my branch' to github repo.

Now, as I understand on github in 'my branch' I have full data about project (including my changes)

how to download this branch on my local machine with a git files?

I mean this as if we make checkout command if we use svn.

Comment: Please, Read the [Github help pages](http://help.github.com/) and the [many resources available online](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=git+pull+branch+from+origin). This is a question that could have been answered with half a second on Google. -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
git fetch origin [remote-branch]:[new-local-branch]
```

Also http://help.github.com/git-cheat-sheets/ is a great resource for git.